# Spark Group By/ Over Partition Has Bad Performance Java

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, hive, apache-spark-sql, analytic-functions

I am trying to run group by query on dataset of 1.4 million records. 
With Hive it takes 2 min while in spark it takes ~40 min with same resources
I am sure I am doing something wrong because this difference between hive and spark with a simple basic query not make sense 
I tried to do it in 2 ways: 
1.

```
Dataset <row> ds = batchDs.select (
col ("key"),
col ("ts")).groupby (col ("key"),col("ts"))
```

2.

```
sparkSession.sql ("select ket ts from x group by key,ts")
```

Both queries take 40 min. I know that in this case I could just do distinct but this is not my real problem. 
I am trying to do over partition and get the same bad performance so I tried to simplify the problem with more basic operation that is very similar to over partition (group by)
And ideas? thank you

Comment: Could you please add how you're running your `spark-shell` or how you're configuring your Spark context (e.g. cores, executors, memory, Spark version, etc.)?

Comment: @Silvio I will add in few min